# How to make JRadioButtons change properties (JFrame)?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox, jradiobutton

How can I make my `JRadioButton` enable/disable a `JComboBox` in `JFrame`?

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly what is in connection between JRadioButton and JComboBox

Answer (score 2):

```
if(radioButton.isSelected())
{
   combo.setEnabled(true);
}
else
{
   combo.setEnabled(false);
}
```

EDIT: Put this code in your event handler of JRadioButton

Comment: Alternatively, `combo.setEnabled(radioButton.isSelected())`.